# Bootstrap input box height has shrunk

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On my site, I am using the bootstrap box, however the line height seems to have shrunk, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I've not modified any bootstrap CSS, only my own but I don't believe this is interfering.

The code I am using is:

```
<div class="pull-left">
<h3>Search for devices</h3>
<p>Use the search form below to search for your device.</p>
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButtons" type="text">
  <button class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Live example here: http://dev.romwars.com/#

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Specify input box height..... height:30px;

Comment: The height is coming from Bootstrap (line 1097 of the un-minified bootstrap.css), but I'm at a loss to see why that height is specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is in quirks mode, because you didn't specify the doctype of the page.

Answer (score 3):

My browser (Chrome) is applying a rule `box-sizing: border-box` in your input. To fix your problem you should put in your CSS this:

```
input[type="text"] {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Also it seems that your problem is what it's described in this question: [What causes the “user agent stylesheet” to use “border-box” instead of “content-box” for box-sizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7534222/1004046). You can solve that putting `<!DOCTYPE html>` above your document.